# REGEX: Any character between two words

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to select all characters (Lorem ipsum...) between the specific words ***"Word1 :"*** and ***"Word2 :"*** How can I select any character between two specific words with Regex?

```
Word1 :
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt

Word2 :
Ut enim ad minim veniam
quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi
```

Comment: `Word1 :\s*([\s\S]*?)(?=\s*Word2 :)` group 1?

Comment: @ctwheels answer is close, but how to exclude "Word1 :" from the result?

Comment: you can't in JavaScript. In other regex flavours you can do a positive lookbehind as `(?<=Word1 :)` or even use the token `\K` to reset the match after `Word1 :`, but JavaScript doesn't allow either of these. You just need to grab the first capture group from the result (which is usually the second item in the array since the first item is the full match)

Comment: As a quick replacement since you know the length of `Word1 :[NEWLINE]` (8 characters - or 9 depending on what kind of newlines you use) you can simply use `match.substr(8);`

Comment: @ctwheels answer is useful for my problem of parsing html tags: ex to get '<div>' as well as '<div class="cc">'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multiline` modifier with `\s\S` to match all characters between your text.

```js
let str = `Word1 :
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt

Word2 :
Ut enim ad minim veniam
quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi`;

console.log(str.match(/Word1 :([\s\S]*)Word2 :/m)[1]);
```